# Question on MLE

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood

[image]

Can I do the part b in this way?I dont have any idea to handle part b.If it is wrong can anyone give me some hints to solve this problem.

Comment: This is a self-study question: you have to indicate where you are stuck and which part you do not understand, rather than asking for verification of your solution.

Comment: This seems on topic to me. The OP has included the tag, shown their work, & is asking for hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution for $(a)$ is correct i.e the mle for $\mu$ is $\bar{X}$ and mle for $\sigma^2$ is $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n}$

Next you should know that $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n}$ is an biased estimator of $\sigma^2$.

But $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n-1}$$ is an **unbiased** estimator of $\sigma^2$ i.e $$E[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n-1}]=\sigma^2$$

You can see from above that $E[\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2)]=(n-1)\sigma^2\tag{1}$

Next your already showed that:

$$\frac{\bar{X}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n}}}$$ is the estimator for $\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$

You already know that $\bar{X}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ are independent.

So, $$E[\frac{\bar{X}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n}}}]=E[\frac{\bar{X}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\bar{X})^2(n-1)}{n(n-1)}}}]$$

And we know sample variance $$S^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n-1}$$

$$E[\frac{\bar{X}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n}}}]=E[\frac{\bar{X}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\bar{X})^2(n-1)}{n(n-1)}}}]=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}}E(\frac{\bar{X}}{S/\sqrt{n}})\tag{2}$$

And according to this [paper](http://scholarworks.gsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1116&context=math_theses) $\frac{\bar{X}}{S/\sqrt{n}}$ has  a noncentral t-distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom and
non-centrality parameter $\frac{\mu\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}$

And read this [paper](http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/course_archive/2010-11/F/6590/Notes/wiki_student_dist.pdf) we can see $E(\frac{\bar{X}}{S/\sqrt{n}})=\frac{\mu\sqrt{n}}{\sigma}$ put it into **(2)**

Finally, $$E[\frac{\bar{X}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n}}}]=\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-1}}*\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$$

This is a biased estimator.

**Interestingly,  this result is the same as my first try (treat $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\bar{X})^2}{n}$ as a constant) if you still remember it. Is it a coincidence?**

Comment: from what i know, if i have i r.v. Y,E(1/Y) is not necessary equal to 1/(E(Y).But why it is true in here?

Comment: Yes, you are right, i will modify my answer

Comment: You mean (1) is a constant,if yes why it is a constant?I don't get it.how to find the expectation of the E(1/(summation sign)^0.5))?

Comment: Hehe, I only **suppose** it is a constant for solving the exercise, I think the professor might give me some credits for the answer if it is for my homework. And I think your solution is good too.

Comment: I find a paper that can solve this problem. http://scholarworks.gsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1116&context=math_theses I will read and modify the answer again later

Comment: Can I use t distribution to do this?Is it a resolvable guess?Since this is a ratio of two R.V.

Comment: Yes, see my modified solution again.

Comment: I have a different answer would you like to take a look?

Comment: Yes, please write as an answer.